# JSF commandButton action is invoked from javascript even if false is returned

Tags: javascript, jsf, commandbutton

JSF 2.1

jsf form

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="userName" value="#{user.name}" />
    <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{user.password}" />
    <h:inputSecret id="passwordConfirm" />
    <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{user.login()}" onclick="checkPassword(this.form)" />
</h:form>
```

javasctipt related code:

```
function checkPassword(form) {
    var password = form[form.id + ":password"].value;
    var passwordConfirm = form[form.id + ":passwordConfirm"].value;
    if (password == passwordConfirm){
        return true;
    }else{
       alert("Password and password confirm fields don't match");
       return false;
    }
}
```

What actually happens:

case 1:user fills correctly the form => the `login()` method is invoked as expected

case 2: user fills incorrectly the confirmed password => the `alert` dialog appears, and when the user clicks the OK button of the dialog, the method is invoked even if `false` is returned!

How to avoid the case 2 behavior, i.e. how to prevent the action to be invoked in case the passwords don't match?

Comment: Do `onclick="return checkPassword(this.form)"` but password related things sensitive. Use an appropriate custom JSF validator instead as client scripts can easily be bypassed by anyone.

Comment: it's just an example, not a real project :)

Comment: thanks Tiny, i had to return it :)